# Why did the Iron Man suits behave this way during the House Party Protocol?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3

At the end of the movie, Tony Stark launches the House Party Protocol and the suits are launched and controlled by JARVIS. The question is:

Why did the Suits attack in hand-to-hand combat with the enemy even though they could keep a safe distance and shoot them with the Repulsors and Uni-Beam?

Comment: Perhaps there is a power limitations, or some kind of cool-off timer?

Answer (score 11):

It might be because JARVIS wanted to conserve power for use by Tony. Though I think there might be another reason why JARVIS didn't have 30~40 autonomous Iron Man suits all bombard the oil tanker which Pepper and Tony are on with repulsors and Uni-Beams...

Answer (score 6):

There are two reasons why I can think of that they don't simply revert to "Just shoot them!" tactics:

- Each suit is designed for a particular purpose.  the **[Iron Legion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man%27s_armor#Iron_Legion)** is made up of suits Tony designed for unique situations, most of them don't involve direct combat.  Some suits, like the one designated ***IGOR*** don't even have repulsor technology as they are designed for things like construction, search and rescue, and exploration.
- Targeting issues.  J.A.R.V.I.S. was in control of all the suits not activley worn by Tony during the skirmish.  This means he would have to split his processing power among 30 or 40 Iron Man platforms.  Each would require locomotion protocols, flight telemetry,defensive postures, power management and all subroutines involved in operation.  To add targeting and fire control management to all the suits would no doubt tax his systems.

Comment: The first point makes sense.  Regarding the second point, it seems like hand-to-hand combat would require significantly *more* processing power (targeting is still necessary, plus dodging, blocking, grappling, etc. become bigger factors).

Comment: @Beofett I would think there's less finesse involved in throwing a haymaker than lining up a shot which would require less processing.

Comment: Aiming an energy weapon, vs. aiming a fist, which necessitates moving the entire arm and part of the torso, calculating trajectory, and anticipating responses (an opponent can dodge even a robotic fist, but an energy beam really isn't going to be dodged).  A fist seems simpler, but in reality I believe it is much more complex from a computing standpoint.

Comment: @Beofett a repulsor blast would be easier to dodge than a punch as it's telegraphed more.  There's also splash damage and what's behind the target to factor in with a beam weapon.